# What are the best ways to calculate the average ratio of two variables in R?

Tags: r

Let's say I want to find the ratio of two variables in a data set (and then eventually find the aggregate mean of the ratio according to a third variable in the data set). What are the best ways to go about this? Presently, I'm trying this out with a large data set where there are both NA and zero values, and everything I try ends up outputting Infinity (I assume because of the presence of zeroes).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add the data you are working with or data that makes your problem/question reproducible to the question the next time. This way we can offer more specific help. When I understood correctly you have data that looks like this:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~V1, ~V2, ~V3,
   1L,  3L, "a",
   3L,  4L, "a",
   2L,  0L, "b",
  54L,  0L, "b",
   6L,  8L, "a",
   3L,  5L, "c",
   3L,  NA, "c"
  )

df

# A tibble: 7 x 3
     V1    V2 V3   
  <int> <int> <chr>
1     1     3 a    
2     3     4 a    
3     2     0 b    
4    54     0 b    
5     6     8 a    
6     3     5 c    
7     3    NA c
```

And want to compute the ratio between two variables (here V1 and V2) and then calculate the mean ratio grouped by another variable (V3). One way of doing this is:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(ratio = V1 / na_if(V2, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(V3) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(ratio, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  V3    mean_ratio
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 a          0.611
2 b        NaN    
3 c          0.6
```

`na_if()` takes care of the division by 0 issue by replacing zeros with NAs.

Edit based on comment:

What the mutate function would look like if both V1 and V2 had NA values to exclude? I thought you wanted to exclude the 0? `na_if()` as used above replaces 0 with NA to prevent division by zero. NAs are excluded in the `mean` function because is set `na.rm = TRUE`. You could use `na_if(V1, 0)` to replace 0 with NA in V1, but why would you want to do this?

Here is an approach with base R:

```
df$ratio <- df$V1 / ifelse(df$V2 == 0, NA, df$V2) 

aggregate(df$ratio, list(group = df$V3), FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Please make sure you understand what these functions are doing before submitting them as homework :) If you do not understand what a function is doing type `?function_name` (e.g., `?aggregate`) to read the documentation.

Comment: Ah, sorry. This is my second post, and I've tried to refrain from posting actual code since it's an assignment, but I understand that makes it difficult to actually address my question. Thank you so much for your reply! Yes, you understand my inquiry perfectly. Is there a way to go about this without tidyverse functions? Also, what would that mutate function look like if both V1 and V2 had NA values that I wanted to exclude? (If there is documentation you can point me toward, more than happy to read up). Thank you again

Comment: No worries. I edited my answer and also included a base R way of doing this. Does this solve your question?